# How can net upgrade size be negative?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Running antergos(based on Arch), I have stumbled across an something that I could not comprehend...

## What is it?

With this being said, after running `pacman -Syy` to synchronize and update my master package database and then running `pacman -Su` to upgrade my system, I get this strange output:

#### Output

```
Total Download Size:    221.05 MiB
Total Installed Size:  1230.56 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        -1.80 MiB
```

Although almost all of the output looks normal, the part I do not understand is how the net upgrade size is negative? The conclusion I came upon is that some package out there must be deleting a lot of its code... Please let me know if this is true or not because it is driving me crazy... Thanks.

Comment: I'd just be guessing, but you're probably correct, and 1.8MiB isn't much.  It's not necessarily 'code', but libraries, documentation, examples, samples, etc., etc.  Packages contain a lot of stuff.  Be happy, you got some space back.

Comment: Thanks @EightBitTony, that was the only explanation that made sense to me so... Yeah!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no need to run `pacman -Syy`, it achieves nothing and just places unnecessary loads on the mirrors, just run `pacman -Syu`.

The reason you are seeing a negative upgrade size is that due to some changes in either upstream or in packaging, one or more of the packages to be upgraded is of a smaller size than the currently installed version(s).

Without full pacman output, it is impossible to say which package(s) are affected, but there could be a myriad of reasons, including:

- refactoring upstream has resulted in less bloat
- functionality has been split out into another package or library
- someone screwed up and forgot to include something and your system is about to explode...

Comment: Wow. Great answer, but isn’t ‘Pacman-Syy’ just updating my master package list? Doesent the ‘-y’ symbolize this? If so wouldn’t the commands be accomplishing the same sorts?

Comment: No, passing `yy` "forces a refresh of all package databases". You don't need to do this every time you upgrade. Just use `-Syu`.

Comment: and what does just `-y` do?

Comment: It syncs the databases (it just doesn't *force* it). See `man pacman`.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the big deal about forcing to sync the databases?

Comment: LIke I said, it is unnecessary, and it creates additional load on the mirrors (which someone has to pay for). It is also bad practice to default to *force* for any operation; you should understand what you are doing and apply force only when it is necessary.

Comment: Without forcing, it downloads the package database files **only** if they have changed since you last downloaded them.  With forcing, it **always** downloads them.  This puts an extra, completely unnecessary  load on the archive servers, and additional bandwitdh fees for the operators.